# How can I draw lines with another background color than the default one in CSS?

Tags: html, css, background-color, lines

I have this really weird problem. I just want to draw two simple lines that are a little bit spaced out between one another.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="hline">

</div>

<div class="hline">

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
html, body {
background-color: white;
}

.hline {
    background-color: black;
    height: 2px; 
    margin: 50px;
}
```

When the background color is of the body is white, it works flawlessly, but when it's black, and the background color of my divs is white, there just seems to be one big white line in the black background. Why is that?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Luke :D

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xb51m04o/ it's working fine for me or I am not getting what you want.

Answer (score 0):

it's working for me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
      background-color: black;
    }
    .hline {
      background-color: white;
      height: 2px;
      margin: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="hline">

  </div>

  <div class="hline">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want... I am using bootstrap though... Could it be because of that?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and this is what I got for a black background and a white line

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body { background-color: black; }
.hline {
    background-color: white;
    height: 2px; 
    margin: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="hline"></div><div class="hline"></div>
</body>
</html>
```